# What is the Regular Expression For "Not Whitespace"

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

Since i try to used this regular expression

```
/name\s+([A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*[A-Za-z0-9])(?!\S)/g;
```

my input that i want is for example:

1. name test
2. name test-name
3. name test-name-2

but when i try to check this input it's also allowed

1. name **test-name** anytext

what i want is after **test-name** shouldn't allowed any whitespaces or characters anymore

Comment: _"shouldn't allowed any whitespaces or characters anymore"_ - So, you want the end-of-line anchor `$`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo My problem I met is when I done my input and I try to add another white space it's still passed the case what can I do for handle it can you explain pls

Comment: You need to use `^` (start of string) and `$` (end of string) to restrict matching anything outside your intended regex. Also your input `name test-name-2` won't match with your regex as you have `[A-Za-z0-9]` at the end of regex and you already have `(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*` which will consume `-2`. A slight modification in regex will do the needful. [Check this](https://regex101.com/r/gROZT6/1)

Comment: If instead of a general answer about regex non-whitespace matching, you want something specific to your data, it would be helpful if you could include some full examples of your data, and the parts you want to match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge it is **\S** (uppercase s). So you can try this:

```
regex = /name\s\S+$/gm
```

[WIKIPEDIA Article for Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

Answer (score 0):

Hi maybe try something like
name\s+([A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*[A-Za-z0-9])(?!\S)(?! )

I added (?! ) so it means that a space is not allowed after your string

[image: I testes it here]

Comment: I try to test my with input "name test-name" it's not passed for this regex :(

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression for the opposite of whitespace (`\s`) is `\S`:

```
public class main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String name = "Stack Overflow is cool";
            //replace non whitespace with *
            String result = name.replaceAll("\\S", "*");
            System.out.println(result);
        }
}
```

The output of this is "***** ******** ** ****". Note that in Java, backspaces have to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
/^name\s+([A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*[A-Za-z0-9])(?:-[\d]+)?$/
```

I have checked the pattern with this test case.

```
const regex = /^name\s+([A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*[A-Za-z0-9])(?:-[\d]+)?$/;

const input1 = "name test";
const input2 = "name test-name";
const input3 = "name test-name-2";
const input4 = "test-name ";

console.log(regex.test(input1));  // Output: true
console.log(regex.test(input2));  // Output: true
console.log(regex.test(input3));  // Output: true
console.log(regex.test(input4));  // Output: false
```

I hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

> Try this!

```
name\s{1}+([A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*[A-Za-z0-9])*(?:-+[A-Za-z0-9]+)(?!\S)(?! )
```

[image]
I hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use end-of-line symbol `$` in your regular expression to make it work.

Modified regular expression **:**

```
/name\s+([A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*)$/
```

RegEx explanation **:**

`/` - The forward slashes at the beginning and end delimit the regular expression pattern.
`name` - Matches the literal string "name" exactly as it appears.
`\s+` - Matches one or more whitespace characters (spaces, tabs, etc.).
`(` - Begins a capturing group. The contents of this group will be extracted as a result.
`[A-Za-z0-9]+` - Matches one or more alphanumeric characters (letters or digits).
`(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*` - This is a non-capturing group `(?: ... )` followed by `*`, which means it can match zero or more occurrences of the pattern inside. The pattern here matches a hyphen followed by one or more alphanumeric characters.
`)` - Ends the capturing group.
`$` - Anchors the pattern to the end of the string. This ensures that the match must occur at the end of the input.

Working Demo **:**

```js
// Input string examples
const inputs = [
  'name test',
  'name test-name',
  'name test-name-2',
  'name test-name anytext'
];

// Regular expression pattern
const regex = /^name\s+([A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*)$/;

// Iterate over the inputs
inputs.forEach((input) => {
  const isMatch = regex.test(input);

  console.log(`${input} : ${isMatch}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with
`name \S+`

Or, if you want strings split by hyphen

```
name \w+(?:-\w+)*$
```